# How was this NFT project able to burn NFT's in other peoples wallets?

Tags: nft, burn

https://exponentials.art/
Had a real-time burn mechanism which burnt NFTs in peoples wallets (they made the nft)/
How is this possible if they don't have access to peoples wallets.

"if the NFT is listed below the current burn threshold, it will be burned (even if it is in your wallet)."

Was this coded into the NFT via a smart contract (how/where would I be able to find that) secondly is this actually possible or is it a scam.

Also if this is possible how where they able to do this real time?

Comment: Do you have the contract address?

Comment: @0xCourtney there contract address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x4c102bb3eaa54a52c85d529786d0d4389f48dd99 (following the opensea collection details) i dont see any anomalies that would let them do it personally so i am puzzled haha

Answer (score 1):

This function might be what you're looking for. It gives anyone with the `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE` the authority to burn an NFT with the matching tokenId. As for whether this is a scam or not I cannot say.

```
  function burnMany(uint256[] calldata tokenIds) public {
    require(hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender()), "Caller cannot alter state");
    for (uint i; i<tokenIds.length; i++) {
      _burn(tokenIds[i]);
    }
    tokensBurned += tokenIds.length;
  }
```