# Can my ERC721 contract burn tokens that are owned by other wallets?

Tags: solidity, burn

If our contract mints ERC721 tokens to different wallets, and we implement `OpenZepplin Burnable`, does the contract have permission to burn tokens that are owned by another wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your burn function has a `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE` in the `hasRole()` in the `require()` function. The `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE` acts as the default admin role for all roles. An account with this role will be able to manage any other role, unless `_setRoleAdmin` is used to select a new admin role.

See:

[How was this NFT project able to burn NFT's in other peoples wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/121430/how-was-this-nft-project-able-to-burn-nfts-in-other-peoples-wallets)

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/access-control